# StackOverflowError при Рекурсии для вычисления цифрового корня

Tags: java, рекурсия, stackoverflow

вот такой вариант кода работает при вычислении цифрового корня:

```
public static int digital_root(int n) {
        while(n>9)
    n=n-9;
    return n;
  }
```

хотел его усовершенствовать при помощи рекурсии:

```
return n <= 9 ? n : digital_root(n-9);
```

вычисляет все верно до int 209502 примерно, а затем уходит в переполнение стека. Хотя циклы сами по себе, на мой неискушенный взгляд, подобные. При этом другие методы рекурсии выполняются нормально на больших int, например этот:

```
return n <=9  ? n : digital_root(n % 10 + digital_root(n / 10));
```

это специфика компилятора при обработке таких рекурсий или у меня ошибка?

Comment: Каждый фрейм стека (он создается при вызове функции) занимает память. Память выделенная под стек ограничена, поэтому количество вложенных вызовов ограничено. Смотрите этот вопрос и ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335378/218971

Comment: спасибо, интересно. таким образом, можно сказать, что в самой рекурсии ошибки нет, просто применять для данного алгоритма ее не стоит ввиду имеющихся ограничений?

Comment: При использовании вычитания в рекурсивном методе, для N = 90000 вложенность вызовов составит порядка 10000 (N / 9), а при делении - порядка 5 (log⏨ N).

Comment: Кто тебе сказал, что рекурсия - это усовершенствование кода программы? Обычно наоборот - создание нерекурсивного варианта приводит к меньшему потреблению памяти при выполнении программы.

Comment: @xmikex да, почитал материалы на тему, действительно, рекурсию следует применять адекватно задаче, в моем случае визуальная _красота_ совсем не соответствует оптимальному решению с точки зрения той же памяти.

Comment: @AlexRudenko да, стало яснее, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри ты должен понимать что такое стек в памяти джава, это стек ячеек с памятью выделенное под вызов метода, то есть если в рекурсии ты вызываешь метод 1000, то и глубина стека будет 1000 ( а вот когда метод заканчивается, он выбрасывается из стека), не важно какой инт, главное какой лимита стека у тебя, ты можешь увеличить его -Xss{память}m, но это неправильно. Рекурсия нужна когда без нее нельзя обойтись, допустим обход дерева в глубину, сама по себе рекурсия нерациональна

Comment: Да, изучил несколько статей на эту тему, стало понятно, что рекурсия далеко не всегда хороший вариант, в моем случае декремент больших чисел с малым шагом и большим количеством вызовов метода-плохая идея. Спасибо.